# Note taking software with Android sync

Tags: software-recommendation, android, sync, notes

I am looking for some notetaking software that has a tree structure in the management of notes and folders. That is, I look for a software that can create multiple notes within a database file. Where possible, the use of the cloud is not required, but the notes can be synchronized, in case I need it in the future.

Also, if possible, recommend a notetaking app that can synchronize with Android offline or online.

Which notetaking software do you recommend?

Comment: Please read the tags and don't try to close this question as a duplicate of any other software recommendation question that won't sync with Android.

Answer (score 3):

Android notetaking apps that are also supported on Ubuntu are:

- **Evernote** – Tusk is an unofficial, featureful, open source, community-driven, free Evernote app. Through the inclusion of optional themes, keyboard shortcuts, custom tweaks, a tray icon, and more, Tusk integrates the Evernote web app with the Linux desktop in ways a regular browser tab can't. To install it type:

  ```
    sudo snap install tusk
  ```

  Features

  • Black, Dark, Sepia & Vibrant themes
  • Focus, Compact & Auto-Night modes
  • Local & global keyboard shortcuts
  • Customizable keyboard shortcuts
  • Export notes as PDF & markdown files
  • Note printing
  • Scalable interface
  • Note navigation
  • Cross-platform
  • Automatic updates
  • Deep OS integration
  • Drag and drop files
- **Simplenote** – Simplenote is an easy way to keep notes, lists, ideas and more. Your notes stay in sync with all of your devices for free. Simplenote is now available for Windows, Mac, Linux, Android, iOS and the web. To install it type:

  ```
    sudo snap install simplenote
  ```
- **Google Keep** – Google Keep is a notetaking service developed by Google. Google Keep is available on the web, and has mobile apps for Android and iOS. Google Keep offers a variety of tools for taking notes, including text, lists, images and audio.
- **Carnet** – [Carnet](https://github.com/CarnetApp/CarnetDocumentation) is a powerful notetaking app the purpose of which is not only to write your shopping list but can also be used to write longer texts, stories, etc. Carnet is available on Android and Linux, also on your web browser with full compatibility with Windows, Mac and Linux, with sync capabilities. To install it type:

  ```
    sudo snap install carnet
  ```

  Features

  • Complete editor: bold/italic/underline/color/highlight
  • Import from Google Keep (only on desktop, then sync on mobile)
  • Insert images / review
  • Open HTML format
  • Organize with folders and choose root storage folder depending on your needs
  • Keywords
  • Quickly see your recent notes
  • Search your notes
  • Protect the app with a pin code (won't encrypt notes) on Android
  • Statistics: words/sentences/characters
  • Sync with NextCloud
  • Record audio
  • Online editor as a NextCloud App

Comment: [Link to Carnet](https://github.com/CarnetApp/CarnetDocumentation) - it's a bit challenging to find, as Google is "polluted" with other referenes to things named Carnet, such as a car selling service, and paper notebooks called Carnet...

Answer (score 1):

**[Joplin](https://joplin.cozic.net/)** is a free and open source note taking and to-do application available for Linux, Windows, macOS, Android and iOS. Its key features include end-to-end encryption, Markdown support, and synchronization via third-party services like NextCloud, Dropbox, OneDrive or WebDAV.

**[Turtl](https://turtlapp.com/)** can be used to take notes, save bookmarks, store documents and images, and anything else you may need, in a safe place. There are Turtl applications available for Linux, Windows, macOS and Android, while an iOS application should also be available in the future. Chrome and Firefox extensions are available to easily bookmark the page you're on, great for quickly saving sites for later.

The Turtl developers offer the service (hosted server) for free, but a premium service is planned for the future. However, the Turtl server is free and open source software, so you can install and use your own instance.

**[NixNote2](https://github.com/robert7/nixnote2)** is a note-taking app that can sync with Evernote (which is available for Android). Nixnote2 2.1 was recently [forked](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/11/evernote-linux-client-nixnote2-forked.html) from Nixnote and includes new features and many bug fixes.

Answer (score 0):

NixNote: http://nixnote.org/ (Can connect to EverNote cloud)